# Nested database transactions in Postgresql 14 and Laravel 9

Tags: database, transactions, laravel-9, postgresql-14

I would like to know what happened if my Laravel 9 code with standard database settings contains nested transactions.
So I have a code which open parent transaction and then open child transaction inside the parent one.
Then I make commit in child transaction and continue. Then I want to make rollback in parent transaction. Does this rollback also rollback the child transaction?
ChatGPT say something about savepoints but I dont trust him much. Can somebod tell me please what will happen and how to rollback the child transaction with the parent one?